# ember Error: Assertion Failed: fullName must be a proper full name

Tags: ember.js, ember-qunit

I got the following error while running a test with Ember.js:

> Promise rejected before "...": Assertion Failed: fullName must be a
>   proper full name

What is the meaning of this error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might also encounter this error if you are using the new nested subfolder angle bracket syntax: `<Foo::Bar />`

Make sure you have the latest version of [ember-angle-bracket-invocation-polyfill](https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-angle-bracket-invocation-polyfill), at least 1.3.0

Answer (score 3):

**Reason**

This error is thrown if `moduleForComponent` is used for a unit test and the first parameter(the name of the component) is started with `component:` prefix.

**How to solve**

You should check the name of the component that is written as parameter for unit test. If `moduleForComponent` is used, then `component:` prefix should not be used. However if `moduleFor` is used, then `component:` prefix should be used like below examples:

```
moduleForComponent('my-component', 'unit: my-component', {
  //test specifications
});
```

or

```
moduleFor('component:my-component', 'unit: my-component', {
  //test specifications
});
```

[This twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/ba05dcf3944edb6aa2b12c2b1ecfe3db?openFiles=tests.unit.components.my-component-test.js%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs) demonstrates usages of both examples.

Comment: I'm having this issue and I do not have a prefix of component: on my moduleForComponent call

Comment: Hello, maybe @Artzt's answer can fix your issue. If you can provide more details, we can look for another fix.

Answer (score 2):

You will also see this horrible message with a malformed route name such as the following:

```
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('mock-test/:accountId/:companyId');
  return null;
});
```

where you have confused the route name with a path segment. Fix it like this:

```
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('mock-test', {
    path: 'mock-test/:accountId/:companyId',
  });
  return null;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the same confusing error after using one colon instead of 2 to separate component name and sub-component.

`<Component:SubComponent />` instead of `<Component::SubComponent />`